# I get this error on Sitecore deployment. What should I do?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Server Error in '/' Application.

Item "/sitecore/content/Home" is not a template.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.InvalidItemException: Item "/sitecore/content/Home" is not a template.

Comment: It would be nice if you add the stack trace to your question

Answer (score 2):

Check your home item template. It should be inherited from Standard Template instead of Template.

Comment: That was it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have selected the item "/sitecore/content/Home" as a template on your startItem (web.config) but it would be nice if you add some additional info!